# Working application fails to use webclient after clickonce deployment

Tags: c#, clickonce

I built an application using C# express 2010 and it works fine on my machine, the deployment succeeds but i can't seem to make it run correctly.

What seems to bug are all the WebClient calls to custom JSON services.

1. In the VS2010, they all work,
2. If i pickup the exe in bin folder it all works fine,
3. But in the ClickOnce install, nope, none work...

What are the possible causes for this...

I tried different ClickOnce security setups, problem persists...

Comment: when you say none work, how do they not work? Any exceptions? Have you got a catch all exception handler swallowing exceptions? It sounds like a security permission issue, but you've not given much to go on!

Comment: Update update, it seems it's related to the webexception permissionset. I setup my application to download from the production server but access data on the development server and so it bugs right there...

Comment: @ImmortalBlue I am now trying to find out how to access any source of information as the application will be hosted on the production server but the user may very well connect to the stage or the prod to edit information with it. Can't seem to find good example to allow that though. :(

Comment: Even more update, when i go to the Security tab for my application, i now see that i'm supposed to have a grid of different permissions i can request, that grid is not there... Could it be a bugged Visual Studio? I'm using Express 2010...

Comment: Is this your first click once application? As for the access information, have you considered using the event log to keep track of any exceptions? It certainly sounds like a permissions issue. As for the security tab, I'm not sure...

Comment: I know i have to add something to the application manifest but i can't find any good example as to what i have to add to it to get the permission to access other websites... if anyone can actually paste me the XML as an anwser that would solve the problem i guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer, it doesn't exist anymore, proof at :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/krimakey/archive/2009/05/20/where-did-my-permission-set-controls-go.aspx

To long answer is: You can setup you trustinfo yourself in XML editor using the following guidelines:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad1fshk(VS.80).aspx